# PLATFORM_INITIALIZER injector token in not working

Tags: angular, angular7

**Problem** PLATFORM_INITIALIZER token is not working and not executed after the platform is initialized.

as per documentation, we can use this token to executed something after the application is initialized/bootstrapped.

**Documentation** says `A function that will be executed when a platform is initialized.`
also, there are very documentation about this token usage and examples.
https://angular.io/api/core/PLATFORM_INITIALIZER

**Already Tried**
I had tried using PLATFORM_INITIALIZER similar to how it has been Unit tested but not got any success.
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/platform-browser/testing/src/browser.ts

**stackblitz link** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zza3af?file=src/app/app.module.ts

```
function initBrowserTests() {
  window.alert('PLATFORM_INITIALIZER called');
}

const featureFlagsFactory = () => {
  window.alert('APP_INITIALIZER called');
  return () => {
    return {};
  };
};

export const appInitializers = [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: featureFlagsFactory,
    multi: true
  },
  {
    provide: PLATFORM_INITIALIZER,
    useValue: initBrowserTests,
    multi: true
  },
];

@NgModule({
  providers: [ appInitializers ],
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Expectation** initBrowserTests() Fn should have been called which I would like to use to initialise my AuthService.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This token is supposed to be passed to `createPlatformFactory` or through `extraProviders` when we call for example `platformBrowserDynamic`:

```
platformBrowserDynamic([{
  provide: PLATFORM_INITIALIZER,
  useValue: initBrowserTests,
  multi: true
}]).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbzyyl?file=src%2Fmain.ts)**

Comment: Thanks @yurzui its works, but PLATFORM_INITIALIZER happens before APP_INITIALIZER, is there is any other token I can use to bootstrap my AuthService after the app is initialized.

Comment: Of course it happens before since platforms are created first

Comment: do you know any token which I can use to initialize my AuthService after app is bootstrapped?

Comment: @yurzui do you have inside info? how did you know that? :) when you say "for example" do u have another example?